# Add a subchild in xml using Tinyxml

Tags: c++, tinyxml

Hi im trying to add a subchild to my XML generated file. I've been reading through the manual and I can't quite figure out how to add it in my C++ code. Any ideas ?

**Current code:**

```
#include <Tinyxml.h>
TiXmlDocument doc;  
TiXmlElement* msg;
TiXmlDeclaration* decl = new TiXmlDeclaration( "1.0", "", "" );  
doc.LinkEndChild( decl );  

TiXmlElement * root = new TiXmlElement( "myroot" );  
doc.LinkEndChild( root );   

TiXmlElement * msgs = new TiXmlElement( "parent" );  
root->LinkEndChild( msgs );  

msg = new TiXmlElement( "child" );  
msg->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText( "Welcome to my child" ));  
msgs->LinkEndChild( msg );  

doc.SaveFile( "tree.xml" );
```

**Current output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<myroot>
    <parent>
        <child>Welcome to my child</child>
    </parent>
</myroot>
```

**desired xml file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<myroot>
    <parent>
        <child>Welcome to child
             <subchild>Welcome to my child2</subchild> 
        </child>
    </parent>
</myroot>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're missing some basic understanding of XML for now. I [fixed your sample](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62746971/revisions), but really this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just repeat those lines:

```
msg = new TiXmlElement( "child" );  
msg->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText( "Welcome to my child" ));  
msgs->LinkEndChild( msg );
```

So, e.g. in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::string name = "child" + std::to_string(i);
    msg = new TiXmlElement(name);
    msg->LinkEndChild(new TiXmlText("Welcome to my " + name));
    msgs->LinkEndChild(msg);
}
```

### Full Demo

```
#include <tinyxml.h>

int main() {
    TiXmlDocument doc;
    TiXmlElement* msg;
    TiXmlDeclaration* decl = new TiXmlDeclaration("1.0", "", "");
    doc.LinkEndChild(decl);

    TiXmlElement* root = new TiXmlElement("myroot");
    doc.LinkEndChild(root);

    TiXmlElement* msgs = new TiXmlElement("parent");
    root->LinkEndChild(msgs);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::string name = "child" + std::to_string(i);
        msg = new TiXmlElement(name);
        msg->LinkEndChild(new TiXmlText("Welcome to my " + name));
        msgs->LinkEndChild(msg);
    }

    doc.SaveFile("tree.xml");
}
```

Result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<myroot>
    <parent>
        <child0>Welcome to my child0</child0>
        <child1>Welcome to my child1</child1>
        <child2>Welcome to my child2</child2>
        <child3>Welcome to my child3</child3>
        <child4>Welcome to my child4</child4>
        <child5>Welcome to my child5</child5>
        <child6>Welcome to my child6</child6>
        <child7>Welcome to my child7</child7>
        <child8>Welcome to my child8</child8>
        <child9>Welcome to my child9</child9>
    </parent>
</myroot>
```

### UPDATE

To the comment:

```cpp
msg = new TiXmlElement("child");
msg->LinkEndChild(new TiXmlText("Welcome to my child"));
msgs->LinkEndChild(msg);

for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
    std::string name = "child" + std::to_string(i);
    TiXmlElement* child = new TiXmlElement(name);
    child->LinkEndChild(new TiXmlText("Welcome to my " + name));
    msg->LinkEndChild(child);

    msg = child;
}
```

Result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<myroot>
    <parent>
        <child>Welcome to my child
            <child1>Welcome to my child1
                <child2>Welcome to my child2
                    <child3>Welcome to my child3
                        <child4>Welcome to my child4
                            <child5>Welcome to my child5
                                <child6>Welcome to my child6
                                    <child7>Welcome to my child7
                                        <child8>Welcome to my child8
                                            <child9>Welcome to my child9</child9>
                                        </child8>
                                    </child7>
                                </child6>
                            </child5>
                        </child4>
                    </child3>
                </child2>
            </child1>
        </child>
    </parent>
</myroot>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time but my goal was to generate a subchild of the child element :)

Comment: Wow. Then how did you come up with that example...? Anyways: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i found out how to do it with adding these line to my code

```
TiXmlElement* msg2;
msg2 = new TiXmlElement( "subchild" );  
msg2->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText( "Welcome to my child2" ));  
msg->LinkEndChild( msg2 );
```